# Autoplay Full Background Vimeo Video

Tags: jquery, html, css, background, vimeo

I am trying to add a background video capability to my website. I do not want it to be clicked. I need it to run automatically, and then loop back to the start on completion. There seem to be a number of JQuery library attempts do so (OKVideo, Vide, BigVideo), but I haven't been able to get any to work. The simpler the better, and if you have a preference I'd love to hear it. Thanks as always.

Comment: Does the player have to be Vimeo?

Comment: I''d prefer it because of their reliability, but not necessarily

Comment: Do you have access to the files? Would you be open to using HTML5?

Comment: I'd prefer they be external, if that's what you mean Hunter.

Comment: I think HTML5 is the best and easiest for what you want to do, but you'd have to make a few versions of the video format. I can post an answer if this sounds like something you'd want to try.

Comment: Totally, let's try it - Thanks Hunter!

Comment: Try taking a look here https://vimeo.com/help/faq/sharing-videos/embedding-videos#how-do-i-set-videos-to-autoplay-or-loop-when-i-embed-them you should be able to do all this just fine with vimeo and no external libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we actually get this feature request a lot and have something in the works that would probably solve this issue in the near future. In the meantime, there is an undocumented `?background=1` query string option that you can append to your embed url to achieve what you're trying to do.

Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/v58x65ba/

Comment: Thanks Sean, this is just what I was looking for! Glad to hear you are working on things like this over at Vimeo.

Comment: It would be great if the the Vimeo API included the `background=1` option when retrieving oEmbed code. I assume this feature is still "experimental" and hope that a solution is still in the works.